# lwjgl not drawing vertex buffer

Tags: lwjgl

Im try to get a super simple lwjgl app going that draws a simple triangle, but cant find the right order of calls to make anything meaningful appear. im using a simple vertex buffer and no shaders.

for some reason each frame is a white triangle on the lower right side of the frame, regardless of what is in the actual vertex buffer.

```java
public void run() {

    GLFWErrorCallback.createThrow().set();
    glfwInit();
    glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    long h_window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "test", 0, 0);
    glfwShowWindow(h_window);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(h_window);
    GL.createCapabilities();

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    int b_vertex = glGenBuffers();
    float[] vertex = {
            0,0,0,
            0,0,0,
            0,0,0
    };
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, b_vertex);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(h_window)) {
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, b_vertex);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0L);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(h_window);
        glfwWaitEventsTimeout(1f / 30f);
    }

}
```

im definitely missing something, but have no idea what it is. here is what this shows:

[Screenshot of Running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeMRD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
```

is for shaderless buffer descriptions

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0L);
```

is for buffer descriptions that also bind buffers to shader inputs